# Custom Image Sizing Mode for ImageButton in xamarin.forms

Tags: image, xamarin, image-resizing, imagebutton

### Situation

I am currently exploring android development on xamarin and therefor decided to develop a small game.

Within the game, I have an `ImageButton` to access some menus. For instance the level up screen.
I made some low res image for the image button:

[image]

### Issue

Now, if I use this in the image button, the image gets scaled up and therefore looks Blurry:
[image]

I guess, the reason being is bi-linear image sizing.

The proper implementation for my specific case would be sizing with nearest neighbor, as it preserves the low pixel look:

[image]

### Question

How would I go about changing this? I have found code for WPF winforms but realized that xamarin has different calls...

```
class ImageButtonWithHardEdgeExpansion : SomeControl
{
    public InterpolationMode InterpolationMode { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs paintEventArgs)
    {
        paintEventArgs.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode;
        base.OnPaint(paintEventArgs);
    }
}
```

For an intermediate workaround, I can use an external image resizer and store the image in high res... but that defies the purpose for me a little. so I am looking for a more long term solution.

Comment: Are you working on Xamarin.forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: it appears to be xamarin.forms

Comment: Does change the [Aspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton#imagebutton-appearance) of  imageButton work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **padding** to do this.

Before padding:

[image]

After padding:

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31552914)